# How to close WPF window inside of a Task

Tags: c#, wpf, task, freeze

I need to run a task to check the connection.

My windows should not be frozen during this check.

So I start the Task, and close my window at the end of this task.

But this returns an exception: InvalidOperationException:'The calling thread cannot access this object because another thread owns it'.

Like this :

```
        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ConnectionState = false;

                if (NetworkTools.CheckGlobalConnection() == (ConnectionStatus.NetworkConnectionSuccess, ConnectionStatus.ServerConnectionSuccess))
                {
                    ConnectionState = true;
                }

                this.Close();
            });
        }
```

How do I close my window at the end of the task without freezing it and without having this exception ?
 (I have a progress bar that rotates indefinitely)

Comment: invoke it? anything on the UI has to be invoked from a thread

Comment: Use Application thread as delegate to close the window

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or you could just use *async await*. `Task.Run` will offload and the await will create a continuation on current SynchronizationContext. In turn giving control back to the *UI* and closing on the right thread.

```
private async void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   await Task.Run(() =>
         {
            ConnectionState = false;

            if (NetworkTools.CheckGlobalConnection() == (ConnectionStatus.NetworkConnectionSuccess, ConnectionStatus.ServerConnectionSuccess))
               ConnectionState = true;
         });

   this.Close();
}
```

<sub>Also as noted, `Calling ConfigureAwait(false)`, would not be the right thing to do in this case</sub>

Comment: Waiting for some enlightenment

Comment: I downvoted since it is too special and does not provide any insight on the `Dispatcher`ing.  At least, provide some comments to explain that this is not the generally correct way to achieve required behavior.

Comment: BTW, you might also specify that `.ConfigureAwait(false)` will cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Dispatcher` to queue window closing logic on the unique UI thread. 
Something like 
`Dispatcher.Invoke(
  () =>
   {
     // close window here
   });`

Whatever is passed into `.Invoke(...)` as a delegate, is invoked on the UI thread and hence has right to access all UI elements. It is common (and the only correct) way to deal with UI-mutations within non-UI threads.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate method you can use ContinueWith

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
         {
            // Your code

         }).ContinueWith((tsk) =>
         {
             this.Close();
         }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```